# git fetch a tag from a remote, but could not see it from "git tag"

Tags: git, fetch, tags, git-remote

git fetch a tag from a remote, but could not see it local.

```
git remote add remote1 c:\repo\project1.git
git fetch remote1 tag_1.0

    From c:\repo\project1
        * tag           tag_1.0  -> FETCH_HEAD

git tag
```

git tag does not show the fetched tag tag_1.0. How to list the tag and create a branch from the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a local tag `tag_1.0`,

```
git fetch remote1 tag_1.0:refs/tags/tag_1.0
```

And then to create a branch `foo` from the tag,

```
git branch foo tag_1.0
```

After `git fetch remote1 tag_1.0`, the commit referenced by the tag is stored in `FETCH_HEAD`. So, we can also create the local tag and branch based on `FETCH_HEAD`.

```
git fetch remote1 tag_1.0
# There should be no other fetch/pull commands here, otherwise FETCH_HEAD could be rewritten by another commit
git tag tag_1.0 FETCH_HEAD
git branch foo FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: git fetch remote1 tag_1.0:refs/tags/tag_1.0, which one is remote? I am confused because of the same tag name.  can I use "git fetch remote1 tag_1.0:tag_1.0"? For branches, git fetch remote1 branch_foo, I can see the branch_foo in local by git switch. Do not know what is the difference. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to see what the current FETCH_HEAD refers to?

Comment: @eastwater To find which commit the current FETCH_HEAD refers to, you can use `git log -1 FETCH_HEAD` or `git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD`. It's okay to use `git fetch remote1 tag_1.0:tag_1.0`. Whether a local tag would be created by `git fetch <remote> <tag>` depends on some git config value, but I'm not sure. In order to make sure it's to be created, we can use the syntax `git fetch <remote> <tag>:<tag>`, which specifies the local ref explicitly. And `refs/tags/<tag>` is more specific than `<tag>`.